# change to string url php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

How are you?

I want to change the link of my site , because it is very ugly , I want it to be like wordpress , I didn't know how can change it , so I ask you to help me please

`http://example.com/?id=43434` => `http://example.com/?category=sport`

how can change it to:

`http://example.com/post/43434` => `http://example.com/category/sport`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with like this,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post/(\d+) index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+) index.php?category=$1 [L]
```

I also recommed using php frameworks. They make it easy to use beautiful urls. You can begin with codeigniter.

Also, this is a good article for beginners: http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite